# Complexity of the "Search words/strings in Matrix of Char" Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, time-complexity

I have a task to search in a grid of letters (`20×20 <= MxN <= 1000×1000`) words (`5 <= length <= 100`) from a list. Any word hidden in the grid is always in the form of a zig-zag segments whose length may be only 2 or 3. Zigzag segments can only be from left to right or from bottom to top.

The complexity required is equal to the product of the number of letters in the grid and the number of letters from list.

For grid:

```
••••••••••••••••••••
••••••••ate•••••x•••
•••••••er•••••••e•••
••••••it••••••••v•••
••••ell••••••a••f•••
•••at••••e••••••rbg•
•••s•••••••ga•••••••
```

and list of  words `{"forward", "iterate", "phone", "satellite"}`
output will be

```
3,6,iterate
6,3,satellite
```

I did this in `C++`:
I saved all prefixes and words in an `unordered_map<string, int>` where `key` is prefix/word and `value` is 1 for prefix and 2 for word. Now I do something like this (pseudocode):

```
for (char c in grid)
    check(c + "");
}
```

where:

```
check(string s) {
    if s is key in unsorted_map {
        if (value[s] == 2) //it's a word
            print s; //and position
        if (not up 3 time consecutive) //limit the segments <= 3
            check(s + next_up_char_from_grid);
        if (not right 3 time consecutive)
            check(s + next_right_char_from_grid);
    }
}
```

This implementation works great for random chars in grid and words from dictionary but 
 complexity C ≃ O(M * N * 2<sup>K</sup>) > O(M * N * R) 
 A better approximation C ≃ O(M * N * (1,6)<sup>K</sup>) because of the restrictions of length segments

```
M * N = number of chars in grid
K = the maximum length of any word from list (5 <= K <= 100)
R = number of chars in list of words
```

Worst case: max grid, max word length and same single char in grid and word
How can I archive the required complexity? It is possible only with the given restrictions?

Comment: What is K in your complexity?

Comment: K = the maximum length of any word from list `(5 <= K <= 100)`. For `{"forward", "iterate", "phone", "satellite"}` K = strlen("satellite") = 9

Comment: I guess that you need a algorithm for a word search puzzle stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Your `check()` function will do many repetition work.

For grid

```
•aa
ab•
aa•
```

and word `'aabaa'`

There are two ways to get `'aabaa'` which are same after letter `'b'`

(top, right, top, right) or (right, top, top, right)

From this trait, we use an array `a[position][n][m]` to record whether for a specific word its prefix with length `position` can be got at grid `[m, n]`

For the previous example, 
follow such sequence

```
a[0][2][0] = true
a[1][1][0] = a[1][2][1] = true
a[2][1][1] = true
a[3][0][1] = true
a[4][0][2] = true
```

`'aabaa'` can be found in grind

So complexity will be `N*M*K*S`

`S` is the number of words in list